# Prevent MySQL client to save passwords into ~/mysql_history

Tags: mysql, mysql-cli

I use `mysql-client 5.55.9999` and I would like to know how to prevent the mysql-client to save passwords to `~/.mysql_history`? Let's say, I create a new user:

```
CREATE USER "username"@"host" IDENTIFIED BY "thePassword";
```

This statement is being put exactly as it is into `~/.mysql_history`. This is what I don't want. I remember in earlier versions of mysql-client, rows including passwords have not been put into the history file, but I don't remember what the exact option in the settings was.

Comment: Which version are you using? The feature is already implemented in 5.6.8, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-logging.html

Comment: ok, but how do I disable that for `mysql-client 5.55.9999`?

Comment: As state in the documentation, as well in the one for version 5.5 (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-logging.html), you can disable the login all together to create a symlink to `/dev/null`.

Comment: yes I know that I can symlink to `/dev/null`, but then I loose the whole history, I don't want that :)